# SQL Server: bulk insert node into xml joined to another table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've googled but can't find a good example of this.
I have a #temp table with an pk ID and decimal column

```
ID    decimal
2     0.34
3     0.1
```

I have another table called master having a column with the same pk and an xml column like:

```
Master
ID    xml
2     <Form ....
3     <Form.....
```

I need to insert a new node into the xml that has its element name as the decimal value. All which have the same element name and at the same level.

The xml on a basic level looks like:

```
<Form formCode="123">
   <Node1>234</Node1>
   <Node2>234</Node3>
</Form>
```

And I want the final xml to look like:

```
<Form formCode="123">
   <Node1>234</Node1>
   <Node2>234</Node3>
   <NewNode>0.34</NewNode>
</Form>
```

I think it should be something like:

```
UPDATE Master
SET 
xml.modify('insert /Form/'...followed by some kind of join.
```

Comment: Please give a little bit more information. Especially how your XML looks like (`<Form...` is not enough) and how and what you want to insert.

Comment: Before and after xml added

Comment: OK, much better, but are you sure, that you want your nodes named like you do it? Normally such nodes would all have the same name. Their "index" is derived from their position in the tree. Another way would be to set an attribut into the node... I would not use different node names here...

Comment: Those are not the actual names of the nodes in my xml, just sample ones for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, decimalColumn DECIMAL(4,2));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (2,0.34)
,(3,0.1);

DECLARE @master TABLE(ID INT, xmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @master VALUES
(2,
'<Form formCode="123">
   <Node1>234</Node1>
   <Node2>234</Node2>
</Form>')
,(3,
'<Form formCode="456">
   <Node1>234</Node1>
   <Node2>234</Node2>
</Form>')

UPDATE @master SET xmlColumn.modify('insert sql:column("NewNode.AsXml") as last into /Form[1]')
FROM @master AS m
INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON tbl.ID=m.ID
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(tbl.decimalColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('NewNode'),TYPE) AS NewNode(AsXml);

SELECT * FROM @master
```

The result

```
2   <Form formCode="123"><Node1>234</Node1><Node2>234</Node2><NewNode>0.34</NewNode></Form>
3   <Form formCode="456"><Node1>234</Node1><Node2>234</Node2><NewNode>0.10</NewNode></Form>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot a cast... The effect was a new Node with the name "NewNode/decimalColumn"...

Answer (score 1):

Use `UPDATE ... FROM` and the `sql:column` function:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int, d decimal(10,2));

DECLARE @master TABLE  (id int, x xml);

INSERT @temp
VALUEs (2, 0.34),(3,.1);

INSERT @master 
VALUES (2, '<Form><Test /></Form>'), (3, '<Form><Test /></Form>')

UPDATE m
SET x.modify('insert <NewNode>{sql:column("d.d")}</NewNode> after (/Form/Test)[1]')
FROM @master m
INNER JOIN @temp d
ON m.id = d.id

SELECT * FROM @master
```

Comment: Using the `{...}` to use a `sql:column()` directly was new to me... Thx and worth an upvote!